# Unserializing a column in a database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a messed up column in my database (I'm using Postgres). The column in the database is of **jsonb** type and it was serialized as an Array. I don't know how that happened, but I need to unserialize everything and store the existing information as an array of JSON.

I have tried searching for existing answers, but it seems that nobody had the exact problem. Also, there used to be **unserialize_attribue** method in previous versions of rails, but it is not there anymore in Rails 5.2.

```
# orders.rb
serialize :content, Array
```

The data saved in the column looks something like:

```
"---\n- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\n  id: 21\n   title: Salade César\n  price: 10\n  tax_rate: '0.0'\n  quantity: 1\n  options: []\n- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\n  id: 22\n  title: Steak\n  price: 14\n  tax_rate: '0.0'\n  quantity: 1\n  options: []\n"
```

I want to transform the current data into a good ol' JSON. Something like:

```
[
  {
    id: 21,
    title: "Salade César",
    price: 1, 
    tax_rate: '0.0',
    quantity: 1,
    options: [],
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    title: "Steak",
    price: 14, 
    tax_rate: '0.0',
    quantity: 1,
    options: [],
  },
]
```

Comment: Hello! I have a related problem and was wondering - did you create the db column with any default value? If so, what was it?

Comment: @michalvalasek , initially the default value was `{}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You can use `YAML.parse` for this, then its built in `to_ruby` method:

```
str = "---\n- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\n  id: 21\n  title: Salade César\n  price: 10\n  tax_rate: '0.0'\n  quantity: 1\n  options: []\n- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\n  id: 22\n  title: Steak\n  price: 14\n  tax_rate: '0.0'\n  quantity: 1\n  options: []\n"

YAML.parse(str).to_ruby
# => [{"id"=>21, "title"=>"Salade César", "price"=>10, "tax_rate"=>"0.0", "quantity"=>1, "options"=>[]}, {"id"=>22, "title"=>"Steak", "price"=>14, "tax_rate"=>"0.0", "quantity"=>1, "options"=>[]}]

YAML.parse(str).to_ruby.to_json
# => "[{\"id\":21,\"title\":\"Salade C\\u00e9sar\",\"price\":10,\"tax_rate\":\"0.0\",\"quantity\":1,\"options\":[]},{\"id\":22,\"title\":\"Steak\",\"price\":14,\"tax_rate\":\"0.0\",\"quantity\":1,\"options\":[]}]"
```

N.B. your string in the question is invalid YAML, which meant this wasn't working to begin with, and as such the answer below :)

---

**Original Answer**

The built in parser isn't working for this, so here's a simple Ruby solution:

```
str = "---\n- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\n  id: 21\n   title: Salade César\n  price: 10\n  tax_rate: '0.0'\n  quantity: 1\n  options: []\n- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\n  id: 22\n  title: Steak\n  price: 14\n  tax_rate: '0.0'\n  quantity: 1\n  options: []\n"

DELIMITER = "!ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess".freeze

str.split(DELIMITER).each_with_object([]) do |yaml_hash, array| 
  hash = yaml_hash.lines.each_with_object({}) do |line, hash|
    stripped_line = line.chomp.delete(' ')
    k, v = stripped_line.split(':')
    hash[k] = v if k && v
  end

  array << hash unless hash.empty?
end.to_json
```

Basically, you use the serialized `!ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` to split the stored string into hashes, then iterate through these mapping to their respective hashes.

Let me know how you get on with this or if you've any questions - hope  it helps.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The `YAML.parse` solution worked like a charm.

Also, you've mentioned that the string was invalid. Surprisingly enough, everything was working fine when serialized as an Array.

Comment: Great, glad it's helped @elvinas! Might just be a copy / paste issue re the string in the question, though if you output it with `puts` you'll notice an extra space before the first `title`, which screws with the indentation :)

Comment: Yes it worked +1, but did you check with `to_yaml` ? Also How OP got string in such format ? It is only possible if `attributes_before_type_cast` is used

Comment: Works like charm! This is very useful if you want to store JSON string instead of Ruby Hash in the database. Then use `store_accessor` instead of `store` in the model. This wy complex PostgreSQL JSONB queries can work, unlike if it is stored in Ruby Hash.